# Why is typedef vector<int> not working in Codeblocks?

Tags: c++, vector, typedef

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

typedef long long int ll;
typedef vector<int> vi;
typedef pair<int,int> pi;

int main(){
ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);
cin.tie(NULL);
int num;
while(cin>>num){
    vi.push_back(num);
}
for(int i=0;i<vi.size();++i){
    cout<<vi[i]<<"\n";
}

return 0;
}
```

This code is giving me "error: expected unqualified-id before '.' token|". But why? Plz help me to understand it.

Comment: Voting to close as a typo.  `vi` is a type, not a variable.  You need a create an object of type `vi` and use that.

Comment: Yes that. There is no initialized variable called `vi`.

Comment: Please [don't include `<bits/stdc++.h>`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h). Also please don't define macros or type-aliases for commonly used type, that will only make the code harder to read and understand.

Comment: I'm not sure it's a typo. OP may not understand the distinction.

Comment: As for your problem, perhaps you should spend more time reading [good books](https://stackoverflow.com/a/388282/440558) rather than spend it on online judge/competition sites (which usually provide template code similar to yours). Such sites are not for learning the basics, and are not a teaching resource (unless all you want to learn is how to be a bad programmer that only knows how to write code for such sites, and not much else).

Comment: @someprogrammerdude, although you may be right, this is harsher than needed.

Comment: It's gotten to the point where there should be something on *how* to post online judge questions and/or this "competitive programming" stuff.  We are not online judges, there is no competitive programming speed tests here.  Thus the code should be written coherently, sanely, and as professionally as possible, and not just copied and pasted verbatim as what you gave the judge website.

Comment: I don't see how it's harsh. OP wasn't attacked or demeaned for using a competitive programming site. And I heartily agree with that opinion on competitive coding sites. They are garbage for learning. Sure they can be a little bit fun here and there, but when you fail their tests, you get zero feedback on why or what data set failed, making it nigh impossible to debug. They actively discourage human-readable code in favor of showing off how "smart" you are. They only seem to encourage the worst of practices.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want this:

```
#include <vector>    // get rid of <bits/stdc++.h> which is not standard
#include <iostream>  // and include the proper headers

using namespace std;

vector<int> vi;    // you want to declare a variable vi, not a type vi
                   // and also get rid of typedefs which only cause confusion
int main() {
  ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);
  cin.tie(NULL);
  int num;

  while (cin >> num) {
    vi.push_back(num);
  }

  for (int i = 0; i < vi.size(); ++i) {
    cout << vi[i] << "\n";
  }

  return 0;
}
```

**Bonus:**

You can replace this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < vi.size(); ++i) {
  cout << vi[i] << "\n";
}
```

with this, which is more idiomatic:

```
for (auto & value : vi) {   //meaning: for all values in vi:
  cout << value << "\n";    //             print value
}
```